# Prestigious institutions with open admissions policies

Tags: open-access, graduate-admissions

Has any college in the US managed to unite being prestigious and being open access, at undergrad or grad level. I mean open enrolment in the European sense, where they have kind of minimal requirements (language cert, high-school and not much more).

I wonder, given that they could charge thousands $/year, what's the problem with admitting mass-wise new students (and provide them with decent teachers, materials and the like). Why limit the number of clients you get?

Answer (score 5):

There are two fundamentally opposing ideas here. Yes, it would be nice if everyone could afford, and be admitted to, a top-tier university. But that's simply not how prestige works.

- If you admit lower quality students, the number of truly excellent graduates is diluted and your university will lose prestige.
- The loss of prestige may mean a gradual decrease in the quality of faculty, as the very best are hired by other prestigious universities. You'll certainly need to hire more professors to teach the extra students, and can you be sure that all the new hires will be just as good as those you've already got? There are only so many researchers in the world worthy of Nobel prizes.

An everyman's university will never have the prestige of a university such as Oxford, Caltech, or MIT. The key to the success of these top universities is *consistency*. Damn near every one of their graduates is a top performer, which is very desirable to employers (and also quite attractive for prospective faculty).

Once you lower the barrier to entry, their perceived quality will head downwards, and the flow-on effects will snowball.

There are many very excellent (and open) universities that are not as *prestigious* as they perhaps deserve, for example ETH Zurich is a truly excellent university that is open to all Swiss citizens who have passed their high school exams. [This Times Higher Education ranking page](http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/world-university-rankings/2014/reputation-ranking) shows somewhat quantitatively the elitism that is at play.

Comment: Don't Oxford, Caltech, or MIT have  legacy admission? Or being admitted as athlete, minority and the like? Or any other non-academic rules that push the level down?

Comment: How can some universities in Europe (apparently not in the UK), be prestigious and still open?

Comment: @QuoraFeans See my updated answer. They may be extremely good, but they don't command the level of _prestige_ that they perhaps deserve.

Comment: Oxford, at least, have no admissions route other than by academic prowess as demonstrated by results and performance at an interview. Occasionally a strong interview and extenuating circumstances (medical problems, deprived background,  etc) may be allowed to compensate for weaker exam results. However, we're talking "very good" instead of "excellent". I can't comment on CalTech et al.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by prestigious?

Comment: @StrongBad I would define a "prestigious" university as one that is in the top 10 or 15 in the world. The next few hundred are no doubt excellent universities, but most of them don't command _worldwide respect and admiration_ to nearly the same degree. I'm talking about the elitist few at the very top.

Comment: If folks are going to downvote my answer, I'd appreciate knowing why you disagree.

Comment: @Moriarty Don't take it personally. I assume this is one of those cases where people don't *like* your answer and thus downvote it (despite being arguably 100% correct).

Comment: One minor comment though - I am not sure how ETH could be *more* prestigious. In my circles, ETH is widely considered the *by far* best european university for technical sciences.

Comment: Having looked at ETH's admissions policy it seems mad to me. What is to stop 1000 students deciding they want to sign up to course x one year and completely overwhelming the available facilities?

Comment: @nivag Given that the system seems to be working rather nicely since a long time, I assume it is not "mad". For your concrete case: what prevents this from happening is simply basic statistics - you don't get that large, unpredictable changes in student interest in practice, even if you don't specifically prevent it. Small changes are simply covered by small resource re-allocations (e.g., move some TA money).

Answer (score 4):

The best example, that I can think of, of a mainstream US university that is respected at both the national and international levels with a policy that is something like open access is Arizona State University. They have a fixed bar admissions policy: https://students.asu.edu/freshman/requirements

> Applicants must also meet at least one of the following:
>
> Top 25% in high school graduating class
>
> 3.0 GPA in competency courses (4.0 = A)
>
> ACT 22 (24 nonresidents)*
>
> SAT Reasoning 1040 (1110 nonresidents)*

Prestigious is a difficult concept to quantify. To some if it is not Harvard, then it is not prestigious. That said, ASU ranks in the top 150 in both the [US news](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges/arizona-state-university-1081) and [THE](http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/world-university-rankings/2012-13/world-ranking/institution/arizona-state-university) rankings. Which I think puts them well within a reasonable definition of prestigious.

However, I think they are probably on the border of both "open access" and prestigious. That said, Arizona is not a particularly affluent state, so I think there is the potential for the model to work.

Answer (score 1):

In partial disagreement with Moriarty's answer, I think that ETH in Zurich is an excellent example of a university that is both prestigious and open-access.

I was told by people there that the university is very sink or swim, and that each year they routinely fail a majority of the students taking, say, freshman calculus. (And that "freshman calculus" there is more like real analysis in the US.) A bit harsh, but I think necessary if you want to maintain extremely high standards but be open to all.

I don't know of any US university that does this.

Comment: Question is about US universities that have done this, and if not why. This therefore does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: Well, I said that no US university to my knowledge does this. As to why; why is no US university willing to fail 80% of its students? I don't think this admits a factual answer, other than to perhaps say it goes against American culture.

Comment: Indeed, there are many pressures on a US university to have a *high* graduation rate (rankings, etc).

Comment: The "throw everybody in and see who swims" approach is also commonly applied in other open universities, e.g., in Austria. In my alma mater we had graduation rates way below 25% in computer science. *Really* kills us in rankings, but that's more a systemic difference than anything else.